# Error in code from split-apply-combine paper - how to resolve?

Tags: r, plyr

To try and get to grips with data manipulations in R, I've started reading Hadley's paper on [split-apply-combine](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper).

I'm on page 3 and trying to go through the code to understand it.  Unfortunately the code is erroring and my reproduction is faithful (I've done c&p and handtyped).  As I'm trying to learn this stuff and I'm right at the beginning I can't actually tell what's wrong with it. I tried it on both R2.5 and R3.0

```
library("MASS")
library("plyr")
data(ozone)
one<-ozone[1,1,]
month<-ordered(rep(1:12,length=72))
model<-rlm(one ~ month - 1)
deseas<-resid(model)
deseasf<-function(value) {rlm(value ~ month - 1)}
models<-aaply(ozone,1:2,deseasf)
deseas<-aaply(models,1:2,resid)
```

Where the models line errors with `Error: Results must have one or more dimensions.`

Can somebody tell me whether it works for them, or what needs to be fixed/amended if it doesn't and *why*?

*PS - Can't check on http://plyr.had.co.nz/ for errata because my work proxy currently blocks the site!*

Comment: I get the same error. And I don't see any obvious errata on that site.

Comment: Ta Thomas, I'm completely stumped - I think 1:2 should be the margins and both of these variations work: `models <- aaply(ozone, 1:2, sum)` `models <- deseasf(ozone[1,2,])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
models <- alply(ozone, 1:2, deseasf)
deseas <- ldply(models, resid)
```

Comment: agreed. I don't see how you could stack the outputs of `rlm` (a list) into an array... Also, `rlm` should be called with `maxit = 500` to get rid of these "failed to converge" warnings.

Comment: Cheers, these do work and they really help with the issue being the output to a. The text around the code in the paper indicates that it should be possible using aaply so that it outputs arrays to 'reduce cognitive effort'.  Maybe the issue is with a change in output of the rlm since publication?

Comment: Then I think Hadley meant to use `alply` then `laply`, which works too and is a more likely (symmetric/double) typo.

Comment: I guess so, but we're now really far away from what was typed originally! Oh well, the new stuff works, I understand why (rlm can only output a list object)  and the symmetric functions bring the residuals back into an array which could be used easily with the ozone dataset

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a bug in aaply and Hadley has said he will look into it soon:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/manipulatr/kg2wDU96mGM